# JS onclick image redirect to same image html

Tags: javascript, image, onclick

I'm not really sure how to explain this, but what I'm trying to do is: when you click a certain image on the page, have it redirect you to another page, where there's basically the same picture, only the page/link is a html one, not only the path to the image, like this: "file:///C:/Users/x/Desktop/report/img/3.jpg".

The code I've seen around is this:

```
   img.onclick = function(event) {
        window.location.href = this.src + '.html';
    }
```

Everything is generated from JS, so I have no HTML code hard coded.

The above code works if I scratch the '.html' part, but like I've said earlier, it only redirects me to the jpg, or, if I leave the '.html' bit in too, it just goes like this "file:///C:/Users/x/Desktop/report/.html" and nothing shows up.

What I'd like to have is a new html page so I can later add other things/info around my image.

I'm new to programming so I am not really sure how/ if this is possible. Any help is appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Try using `window.location.href = event.target.src + '.html';`

Comment: Getting closer, this is the new URL: "file:///C:/Users/x/Desktop/report/img/3.jpg.html" but still no picture shows up. It gives me error file not found.

Comment: So remove the `.html` because your are searching the file in your folder directory

Comment: Now I'm in the same place I was in earlier: image shows up, but the url is simply the path to the image, so there's no way I could add other elements/tags to that page.
What I want to do is have it displayed in a redirected html page, so I can then manipulate it.

Comment: You are using some front end framework?

Comment: This may no possible, you need to create a new html page only for display images, and send as parameter the name or path of the image

Comment: I'm not using any framework, I'm writing in vanilla JS, nothing else.

Oh, I see. Do you know if I could do that dynamically for each photo, by any chance?

Answer (score 0):

You first have an img tag with the onClick property as follows:

`<div class="col-12 col-md-4 col-lg-3">
      <img onclick="GetImage(@ImageAddress)"/>
</div>`

Then write script :

```
<script>
        function GetImage(imageAddress) {
            window.open(imageAddress);
        }
</script>
```